# Python discord bot warn specific person

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I am doing a bot that will warn a person if the word in the message is blacklisted.
The problem is that when the bot writes @person#tag it is not a mention, but just a text.
How do I improve it?
Here is my code:

```
badwords = ["lal", "sas"]
for word in badwords:
    if message.content.find(word) != -1:
        await message.channel.send("-warn @" + str(message.author))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
badwords = ["lal", "sad"]
for word in badwords:
    if message.content.find(word) != -1:
        await message.channel.send(f"-warn {message.author.mention}")
```

This makes it so that it mentions the author who sent the message

Comment: Anytime @Resadesker